# VS403144: The warehouse database is currently pointing to the same database that was being used on your production deployment

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I am upgrading to TFS 2017 using Production restore backup in DR environment. I run the upgrade using Pre-Production upgrade.

I follow link below to restore database from production to DR
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance#ChangeOwnership

In the Readiness Check while perform TFS Server configuration Wizard i received the following error and this is also what record in the log everything else are execute successfully:

```
VS403130: The Public URL currently has the same value as the one on your production system.

VS403135: The supplied Report Server URL (http://SRS01:80/ReportServer) has not been updated to be different from its previous value.

VS403136: The supplied Report Manager URL (http://SRS01:80/Reports) has not been updated to be different from its previous value.

VS403144: The warehouse database is currently pointing to the same database that was being used on your production deployment.

VS403140: The specified Analysis Services database is the same one being used in your production deployment.
```

**Update**
Using this reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/15/migrating-team-foundation-server-databases/

Note: 
Tfs_Analysis in **SRS01**
Tfs_Warehouse and Tfs_Configuration in **CONTOSO\DB1**

I run this command to remap with analysis

```
TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:CONTOSO\DB1;TFS_Configuration /SQLInstances:SRS01 /AnalysisInstance:SRS01 /AnalysisDatabaseName:Tfs_Analysis
```

and receive an error:
The Team Foundation Server configuration could not be reconfigured. The following errors were encountered:

```
TF246064: No database could be found for the following host: Project1. The host has the following ID: d8e6c04c-78ca-4130-be1b-48c20459fd8a. To fix this problem, use the TFSConfig RemapDBs command-line tool and make sure that you specify the SQL
Server instance that contains this database.
TF246064: No database could be found for the following host: Project2. The host has the following ID: 2057e3ad-16e2-30d0-bbdf-b1720ceac1cd. To fix this problem, use the TFSConfig RemapDBs command-line tool and make sure that you specify the SQL
Server instance that contains this database.
```

If run the following 
`TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName:CONTOSO\DB1;TFS_Configuration /SQLInstances:CONTOSO\DB1 /AnalysisInstance:SRS01 /AnalysisDatabaseName:Tfs_Analysis`

Receive this message:
"The current Team Foundation server configuration is valid. No database connection strings were mapped".

but the following execute and map successfully which i can see the dbstring updated in Tfs_Configuration.tbl.Database:

```
TfsConfig.exe remapdbs /DatabaseName:CONTOSO\DB01;Tfs_Configuration /SQLInstances:CONTOSO\DB01 /continue
```

But if i run with Production Upgrade in DR environment only display this 
  VS403130: The Public URL currently has the same value as the one on your production system.

Another question is raised. Which procedure we need to choose Production Upgrade or Pre-Production Upgrade Testing?

Comment: Have you redirected the DBs and configured Reporting and Analysis Services and others .... ? Whatever, you need exactly following the instructions here to  [Restore data to a different server than the current one for TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance)

Comment: i have followed everything. on the link but still get an error.

Comment: But according to the error message, seems you did not redirect the DBs and configure the Report Server correctly. You need to provide more infromation for further troubleshooting. Check the logs, event etc. Also make sure all the related commands are executed without any error.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT. I have update the question and log and errors

Comment: You need to remap all the DBs, please check the instances first, make sure the DBs existhing there. Then specify all instances, separated by commas, of SQL Server that host databases for Team Foundation Server. For more information, see [RemapDBs Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs).

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT, i have update my question above

Comment: According to this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/test-tfs-upgrades-pre-production-and-production-upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017-2/   the remapDBs command is supposed to be taken care of by the wizard.